# Attempting to change the state of the error variable by calling the setRegisterError function but when it's called the state of error is not changing

Tags: javascript, react-native

**handleSubmit function called in onClick of a button**

```
handleSubmit = async (name) => {
    let registerResponse = await registerAPI(this.state)
    const resultResponse = await registerResponse.json()
    console.log(registerResponse)
    console.log(resultResponse)
    if (registerResponse.status === 200) {
        const userInfo = {
            hasura_id: resultResponse.hasura_id,
            name: name
        }

        let setUserResponse = await setUserAPI(userInfo)
        const resultResponseSetUser = await setUserResponse.json()
        console.log(setUserResponse)
        console.log(resultResponseSetUser)
        if (setUserResponse["affected_rows"]) {
            this.setRegisterError('')
        }
        else {
            this.setRegisterError(resultResponseSetUser.message)
        }
    }
    else {
        this.setRegisterError(resultResponse.message)

    }
  }
```

**setRegisterError function is supposed to change the state of error and if there's no error it's supposed to navigate to a new screen**

```
setRegisterError = error => {
    // If there's an error display that, otherwise send to new screen to tell the user to verify email address and then login
    this.setState({error})
    if(error === '') {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('PostRegister')
    }
}
```

Comment: could it be that message on resultResponse or resultResponseSetUser is undefined? you can simply avoid that possibility by setting default value of error to empty string.

Comment: It turns out I was supposed to check resultResponseSetUser["affected_rows"] instead of setUserResponse["affected_rows"] because the result set is what contains the affected_rows variable